# how to change jboss time zone IST(Asia/Calcutta) to EST(America/New_York) in jboss7.1.1 server

Tags: java, date, jakarta-ee, jboss, openshift

I am using jboss 7.1.1.I want to change time zone IST(India) to EST(New_York).I got one solution for using java_opts option.I put this below code in domain.conf file in bin folder.

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Duser.timezone=America/New_York"
```

After restart jboss server and goto check user.timezone = Asia/Calcutta in boot.log file in log folder.

It's did not change.I want to change time zone Asia/Calcutta to America/New_York.

I do not know how to set custom timezone in jboss, help needed

Comment: Can you try with the default JVM parameters syntax? : `_JAVA_OPTIONS` instead of `JAVA_OPTS`

Comment: The above is something to do with Windows "environment". Not at all what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are running in standalone mode so you can add `-Duser.timezone="America/New York"` to `JBoss installation/bin/standalone.conf.bat` file to JVM options which already present in the file.

domain mode is nothing but many instances of jboss are running and your configuration will for this alone.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "export JAVA_OPTS=\"$JAVA_OPTS -Duser.timezone=Africa/Johannesburg\"" >> /opt/wildfly/bin/standalone.conf
```

Restart and Done